MongoDB Issues with translating JS query to C#
I have a collection which stores information about sirens - notifications. I need to get summarized user statistic by (long) userid:

A count of owned sirens;
A count of subscriptions;
A count of sirens that the user is responsible for

Siren document structure (necessary fields for question only):
{
  "_id": ObjectId( "65fc94593273fc2ab6ff8960"),
  "ownerid": NumberLong( "99999999"), 
  "listener": [
    NumberLong( "11111111"),
    NumberLong( "00000000")
  ],
  "responsible": [
    NumberLong( "11111111")
    ]
}

After 2 days of struggling I've made a working request via JS
db.sirens.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        { "ownerid": userId },
        { "listener": userId },
        { "responsible": userId }
      ]}},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "owner": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$ownerid", userId ] }, 1, 0] }},
      "responsible": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$and": [
                 { "$ne": ["$responsible", null] },
                 { "$isArray": "$responsible" }, 
                 { "$in": [userId, "$responsible"] }
              ] }, 1,0 ] }}
      ,"listener": { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$and": [
                 { "$ne": ["$listener", null] },
                 { "$isArray": "$listener" }, 
                 { "$in": [userId, "$listener"] }
              ] }, 1,0 ] }}   
    }
  }
]);

But here is a concern that I can't solve. fields "listener" and "responsible" may be missing. And in JS this condition:{ "$isArray": "$responsible" }, handles the situation. But I can't do the same in C#.
Here is the code I've got so far:
var query = sirens.AsQueryable<SirenRepresentation>()
    .Where(_sirena => _sirena.OwnerId == userId
                      || (_sirena.Listener != null && _sirena.Listener.Any(x => x == userId))
                      || (_sirena.Responsible != null && _sirena.Responsible.Any(x => x == userId)))
    .GroupBy(s => true)
    .Select(g => new UserStatistics
    {
      SirenasCount = g.Sum(_siren => _siren.OwnerId == userId ? 1 : 0),
      Subscriptions = g.Sum(_siren => (_siren.Listener != null && _siren.Listener.Contains(userId)) ? 1 : 0),
      Responsible = g.Sum(_siren => (_siren.Responsible != null && _siren.Responsible.Contains(userId)) ? 1 : 0)
    });
    
public class SirenRepresentation
{
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("ownerid"), BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]
  public long OwnerId { get; set; }
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]
  [BsonElement("listener")]
  public long[] Listener { get;  set; } = [];
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]
  [BsonElement("responsible")]
  public long[] Responsible { get;  set; } = [];
  [BsonElement("requests")]
//...
}

public class UserStatistics{
  public int SirenasCount{get;set;}
  public int Subscriptions{get;set;}
  public int Responsible{get;set;}
}


When one of the fields is missing an exception is caught:

Exception has occurred: CLR/MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException An
exception of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' occurred in
System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Command
aggregate failed: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by
:: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing.'


Update. Fixed method:
public async Task<UserStatistics> Get(long userId)
{
  var query = sirens.AsQueryable()
  .Where(_sirena => _sirena.OwnerId == userId
                    || _sirena.Listener.Any(x => x == userId)
                    || _sirena.Responsible.Any(x => x == userId))
  .GroupBy(keySelector: x => true,
    resultSelector: (_, _sirens) => new UserStatistics
      {
        SirenasCount = _sirens.Sum(x => x.OwnerId == userId ? 1 : 0),
        Subscriptions = _sirens.Sum(_sirena => (_sirena.Listener ?? new long[] { }).Contains(userId) ? 1 : 0),
        Responsible = _sirens.Sum(_sirena => (_sirena.Responsible ?? new long[] { }).Contains(userId) ? 1 : 0)
      })
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  return await query;
}

Big thanks to Yong Shun <3
P.S. MongoDB.Driver 2.24 also provides behaviour for translation some_array is Array, but unfortunately it is bugged. It translates is Array to expression:
"$cond": {
    "if": {
        "$and": [{
                "$or": [{
                        "$eq": ["$some_array._t", "Array"]
                    }, {
                        "$and": [{
                                "$isArray": "$some_array._t"
                            }, {
                                "$in": ["Array", "$some_array._t"]
                            }
                        ...


And in my case for MongoDB v.7.0.6 it doesn't work properly. But if we change "$eq": ["$some_array._t", "Array"] ->  {"$isArray": "$some_array"} then it will work

As your Listener and Responsible fields are possibly missing, you can provide a default value to the field with:
(_siren.Listener ?? new long[] { })

Thus, when transforming to a MongoDB query, it is equivalent to:
{ "$ifNull" : ["$responsible", []] }

Complete query:
var query = sirens.AsQueryable<SirenRepresentation>()
    .Where(_siren => _siren.OwnerId == userId
        || (_siren.Listener != null 
            && (_siren.Listener ?? new long[] { }).Any(x => x == userId))
        || (_siren.Responsible != null 
            && (_siren.Responsible ?? new long[] { }).Any(x => x == userId)))
    .GroupBy(s => true)
    .Select(g => new UserStatistics
    {
        SirenasCount = g.Sum(_siren => _siren.OwnerId == userId ? 1 : 0),
        Subscriptions = g.Sum(_siren => (_siren.Listener != null 
            && (_siren.Listener ?? new long[] { }).Contains(userId)) ? 1 : 0),
        Responsible = g.Sum(_siren => (_siren.Responsible != null 
            && (_siren.Responsible ?? new long[] { }).Contains(userId)) ? 1 : 0)
    });


It doesn't work in this way. Because it's not LINQ Select, it's a MongoDb.Driver.Linq Select. This method translates conditions from C# syntax to json instructions under the hood for MongoDB. So it can't translate (_siren.Listener ?? new long[] { }).
It has translation of  _siren.Listener is Array but unfortunately it has a bug.

Which MongoDB .NET Driver version are you used? If you use LINQ Provider v3 and you should able to achieve: MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(mongoUrl); settings.LinqProvider = MongoDB.Driver.Linq.LinqProvider.V3;

I use: MongoDB.Driver - 2.24.0. And MongoClient.Client.Settings.LinqProvider* is set to V3 by default

Otherwise, I would suggest you pass the whole query as Export Query to Specific Language  without need to convert to the LINQ query.

Ya, I tested with 2.24.0 version, able to get the result with no error. Would be great if you can share what is the error you get in your end. Thanks.

Yes. You were right.  When I looked at the result, I interpreted it incorrectly. Thanks. It works. Still "is Array" has a bug. I suppose I have to post a bug report to MongoDB JIRA

I've sent a bugreport to the MongoDB team.
And a member of their team helped me a lot with understanding of converting C# language constructs to a json query string. Special thanks to Boris Dogadov.
Long story short:

Null check is not the same as Missing field check.
We can use is T for deserialization purposes of some document into some object of type T. In this case document _t field  has to be set. That's described in this article. But it isn't appropriate way to check if the field is an array.
MongoDB.Driver.Mql - static class that provides tools for checking missing fields

As a result we can check the missing field like this:
Responsible = _sirens.Sum(_sirena => (Mql.Exists(_sirena.Responsible) 
                   && _sirena.Responsible.Contains(userId)) ? 1 : 0)

or
sirens.AsQueryable().Where(x=> Mql.Exists(x.Responsible));

Be aware that Mql methods are applicable only for LINQ queries.
Also there is a detailed answer to another user about subtles of LINQ processing
